# Running [not really] a command inside a command-line program

Tags: java, command, execute

I am making a Java command-line program (call this `parent`) that essentially communicates with a core server and will dynamically boot up another `JAR` command-line based program (call this `child`) inside the parent (using processes).

The thing is, the core server will need to restart all `500+` parent servers when an update is rolled out, and at any given time there can be `250+` parent servers with child processes running inside them.

The child process listens for command line input and will safely shut itself down when it receives `stop` (note that the input streams are linked, so if I type this into the console it will shut down). Now, my question is, how can I have the parent server input text into the command line for the child server to receive? I have tried `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("stop")`, with no avail.

Hopefully I made this clear enough; thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: "command line input". You mean it listens/reads from stdin?

Comment: Yes @MarcB, just a scanner.

Comment: So essentially just a way to inject a String so it can be picked up with a Scanner

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using Java's API for Processes, you should keep a reference to the Process object and write out to it's stdin via [Process#getOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream()).  Depending upon how you're reading from stdin, you'll also want to be sure to write a newline.